# How to define Kronecker product layer of 2 keras layers of shape (None, 4096) is performed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multimodal

Let's say there are 2 different/separate keras layers,
`encoder_1 & encoder_2` with both having output shape of `(None, 4096)`.
Now how to define keras multiply layer which gives `(None, 4096, 4096)` as it's output shape.
Is this same as Kronecker product?
If not the same **please show how to implement Kronecker product of 2 layers** named, encoder_1 & encoder_2?

Comment: Is the first dimension the batch dimension? In which case this is just the outer product of the two length 4096 vectors, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. the first dimension is batch which is None. encoders e_1 & e_2 are technically 1D array of 4096 lengths, the output of flattened layers. So multiplication b/w two inputs with a dimension of (None, 4096) will give output of (None, 4096, 4096). 'None' represents batch.

Comment: by the way, it's name is Bilinear Tensor product not kronecker product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should be able to achieve this simply using either the [`Dot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dot) layer or [`dot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/dot) method of Keras, after inserting dimensions of length 1:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import dot

encoder_1 = tf.expand_dims(encoder_1, axis=2)
encoder_2 = tf.expand_dims(encoder_2, axis=1)
outer = dot([encoder_1, encoder_2], axes=(2, 1))
```

`outer` should be a tensor of shape `(None, 4096, 4096)`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I have one question though. Is this Bilinear tensor product,          encoder_1 ⊗ encoder_2? If not then how to implement Keras layer to perform Bilinear tensor product?

Comment: This is the outer product between the two vectors broadcasted across the batch dimension. The outer product is the specific case of the tensor product for vectors.